# UFO or something else?

Tags: star

It's 5.50 am now in Dhaka, Bangladesh.  I just saw a moving star around 5 am. It was a starry sky and that star was moving in a straight line. It was very fast, faster than regular planes (though I didn't hear any sound) and disappeared in the Eastern sky.  It was a little brighter and a little closer than the other stars. Can anyone tell, what was it?

Comment: The ISS or a satellite, probably.

Comment: Technically, it IS a UFO until you can lose the U.

Comment: If you don't know what it is, then by definition it's a UFO - Unidentified Flying Object. "Unidentified" means you don't know what it is, that's all. It does not mean it's a starship full of aliens, necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

According to this (https://spotthestation.nasa.gov/sightings/view.cfm?country=Bangladesh&region=None&city=Dhaka#.WcATdWdSz0o) the ISS was around at that time of morning. The sunrise was 5:45, so it could have been illuminated by the sun before it rose.